# Magento Product rating calculation performance

Tags: magento

If my web pages show many products (include title and rating), then web page needs to calculate rating percentage by every products with following code.
I am sure this kinds of calculation will slow down my web page.
Is this the only choice that i can choose, or is there any better performance code that i can use?

```
            if (count($reviews) > 0) 
            {
                foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) 
                {
                    foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) 
                    {
                        $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
                    }
                }
                $avg = array_sum($ratings)/count($ratings);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use review model of Magento's core

```
<?php
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); //get store id

//in your product loop 

$review_summary = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($store_id)->load($_product->getId()); //pass product's id to review model
echo $review_summary['rating_summary']; //get rating summary

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used this code, magento use same code on category list page.

```
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
      <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You need to just pass your `$product` object in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get rating on any page:

```
<?php
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($storeId)  ->load($_product->getId());
    ?>
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?> 
<?php if($summaryData['rating_summary']){ ?><div class="rating-box"><div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $summaryData['rating_summary']; ?>%"></div></div>(<?php echo $_product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount(); ?>)<?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```